# JavaScript - Why does this closure not hold parameters?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm reading an [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20080209105120/http:/blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies) on how closures work. I'm understanding almost all of it except for *Section 5* in that [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20080209105120/http:/blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies).

It's talking about how closures work with loops with this example:

```
function buildList(list) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var item = 'item' + list[i];
    result.push( function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])} );
  }
  return result;
}

function testList() {
  var fnlist = buildList([1,2,3]);
  // using j only to help prevent confusion - could use i
  for (var j = 0; j < fnlist.length; j++) {
    fnlist[j]();
  }
}

testList();
```

Three alerts come up, each saying *item3 undefined*. I do understand why it says `item 3`. The closure from the `buildList` function holds a *reference* to `item`, it doesn't hold the actual value.

What I don't get is why `list[i]` comes back as `undefined` in each alert from the `result.push...` line. Doesn't that closure still have the `list` parameter from retained?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Doesn't that closure still have the `list` parameter from retained?

Yes. But the value of `i` will be equal to `list.length` and `list[list.length]` is `undefined`. If an array has length `3`, then the highest accessible index is `2`, not `3`:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(arr[2]); // 3
console.log(arr[3]); // undefined
```

Related: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/218196)

Comment: The value of `i` is list.length *after the loop has run its course* (which it has, by the time you invoke the closure).

Answer (score 1):

`buildList` and it's inner, anonymous function share context to a certain degree. Changing `i`, as is done in the `for` loop, changes it for all the created anonymous functions that are created even after the fact. Change the anonymous function from:

```
function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])}
```

to something like:

```
(function(i){return function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i]);};})(i)
```

This causes a copy of `i`'s value to be made at the time of creation and assigned into another, different `i` that overrides the outer `i` in the context of the returned anonymous function, while still allowing dynamic access to `item` and `list`.